# How can I convert question marks to quotation marks for every result for a specific field in my MS Access query?

Tags: microsoft-access

I have a table that stores all data entered into a program online. Every quotation mark, for whatever reason, is converted into a question mark in the table. Ex: "Hello" would look like:  ?Hello?

When I run a query (and subsequently a report) on this table, I want to convert the question marks back into quotation marks. How can I do this?

(Note: I have no control over the table storing the data or the process that converts the quotation marks into question marks, which I don't want to happen.)

Answer (score 1):

Are you running SQL queries? If so, you can use the `replace()` function to replace one character in a name with another.

```
UPDATE table
SET columna=replace(columna, '?', '"'),
    columnb=replace(columnb, '?', '"'),
    ...and so on
```

Comment: What happens when you actually have a ? elsewhere in the table?  Since I do not have access to the database itself, I am going to guess it is some sort of encoding error. The quotes may actually begin and end quote. The database character set is having a difficult time interpreting those characters and thus giving the question mark. While your answer is technically correct, I do not think it actually addresses the issue of why the data appears that way in the first place.